# How to specify the path for Procfile in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm making a monorepo nodejs app and I would like to specify a `Procfile` for each package in my monorepo.

So far what I found is that the `Procfile` file needs to be in the root folder.

How can I specify the path to the desired `Procfile`?

For example

```
my-app/
  packages/
    server/
      ...other files
      Procfile 
    web/
      ...other files
```

And use the `Procfile` in `packages/server/Procfile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the path. [Procfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.htm) must be in root of your application:

> place a file named **Procfile in the root directory** of your application source.